# Soft Deleting a row with laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a restful user controller with a listing of all users on my index method that is shown in an HTML table. Inside each row in a cell is e link to the edit page for a user and a link to soft delete a user. Right now I have it set up so that it will soft delete the user however I'm trying to work on it so that the link will actually work. What I used to have is just the anchor link however after watching Restful Forms video on the laracasts website I know this can't be done. Jeff Way presented the way of doing this action with Laravel as having to do so in a form.

Can someone suggest to me how to do so with me still being able to keep it looking the way I need it to with the classes assigned to the button and the i element as well?

Also when I click on what I have it goes to the following url which seems odd.

```
http://project.dev/users/{users}
```

I also have a dd($user_id) in the destroy method on the users controller and it keeps coming up NULL.

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ URL::route('users.edit', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
    {{ Form::open(['method' => delete', 'route' => 'users.destroy', $user->id]) }}
        {{ Form::button()}}
        <a href="{{ URL::route('users.destroy', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will something like this work?

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ URL::route('users.edit', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
    {{ Form::open(['method' => delete', 'route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id]]) }}
        {{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-times"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger'])}}
    {{ Form::close() }}
</td>
```

I adjusted the `route` parameter to include `$user->id`, and stuck the `<i>` into `Form::button()` ... Laravel doesn't escape the `Form::button()`'s value, so it goes through unmolested.

Comment: That works perfectly however I'm trying to figure out why the delete button shows up as is underneath the edit link as opposed to being beside.

Comment: By default, `<form>`s are block elements.  You can modify it's style to make it inline or inline-block.  It's kinda sloppy to do it this way, but perhaps something like: `{{ Form::open(['method' => delete', 'route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id], 'style' => 'display:inline;']) }}`

Comment: ... or perhaps add a class, and use a stylesheet to display:inline that class.

Comment: How would I do it as a class.

Comment: `{{ Form::open(['method' => delete', 'route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id], 'class' => 'delete-action']) }}` ... then somewhere in your stylesheet `.delete-action {display:inline;}`

Comment: Your answer deletes without prompting, is there a way to modify this to prompt for confirmation before deleting?

Answer (score 0):

You could make an AJAX call using javascript. with jQuery it could be something like this:

(add ajax-delete class to the a element)

```
$('a.ajax-delete').on('click', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: $this.attr('src'),
        success: function() {
            //dynammicaly remove deleted element from DOM tree here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is true however I'm not using this method.

Comment: I made some changes to my post if you could reevaluate it and respond thank you.